# Gitlab CI/CD stage test fails when fetching external resource with error: dh key too small

Tags: node.js, axios, ssl-certificate, gitlab-ci, eslint

I'm trying to work with Gitlab CI/CD but the test stage fails with the following error:

```
write EPROTO 140044051654592:error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2171:
```

##### gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: node:16.15.1

stages:
  - test

test-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run test
```

To be note that this is an integration test that calls an external resource with axios, and I have tried to set `rejectUnauthorized: false` and `minVersion: "TLSv1"` as suggested [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/535) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69972567/1423384)

```
const axiosOptions = { 
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    minVersion: "TLSv1",
  })
};
const axiosInstance = axios.create(axiosOptions);
const response = await axiosInstance.get('https://www.some-domain.com/some-article.html');
```

This is not a problem with the test itself as it runs fine on my PC, but I suppose with the TLS of the gitlab runner.

Thanks